# How do I get my variable contents entered into my database instead of <?php echo $variable; ?>

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I've inherited some code that takes a user's input, and adds it to a cell in a MySQL database hosted on the same instance. It's not working how it should, however.

Expected behavior: when a user clicks the link, their input is added to the table in MySQL.

What actually happens currently: This code appears in the cell instead of the actual data: `<?php echo $user_email; ?>`

The function call looks like this:

```
function dibs(item_id)
{
    ajax_it("index.php?email=<?php echo $user_email; ?>&item=" + item_id, dibs_complete, dibs_fail);
}
```

And the function ajax_it is:

```
function ajax_it(request, ready_func, fail_func)
{

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    { 
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            ready_func(xmlhttp);
        }
        else
        {
            fail_func(xmlhttp);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", request, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The input is collected like this:

```
        <form action="#" method="GET">
        <input name="email"></input>
        <input name="category" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET["category"]; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>
```

I've tried changing permissions of the javascript, the SQL server access and nothing seems to affect the behavior.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `permissions of the javascript`?

Comment: What _should_ be happening is that PHP substitutes the correct value for `$user_email` into the dibs() function call before emitting it to the browser. It seems that this is not occurring for some reason. You haven't posted the full PHP script, so this is now speculation, but I'd guess that your server either doesn't have PHP installed, or it's not configured to run it.

Comment: Yes I thought that somehow the PHP isn't being executed also. I've set the site up locally on a LAMP VM and i'm seeing the same weird behavior.  PHP appears to be up and running (<phpinfo()> works).

Comment: The Javascript permissions are: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 auction auction 1727 Sep  5 00:49 ajax.js`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your Ajax is set up, but it seems strange to me to use PHP to put the value of a variable in DOM into your Ajax use. Normally you'd select that value using Javascript. But your problem is that you've got the PHP call inserting in the DB. That normally happens when you're calling PHP functions on a page that doesn't support it (like HTML files or external Javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - syntax error.  Apparently JS doesn't like \" much